# Why we need .fit after KFold cross validation

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, k-fold

If cross validation trains our model on training data k number of times then why do we need fit method.

When i am using the below code

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
cross_val_score(model, train_s1, target_s1, cv=5 , scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error')
```

I need to used .fit in order to used .predict. But why ? When already cross validation has train my model on training data.

Answer (score 0):

In cross validation you work on folds (K-Fold) which could be like 3,5,10 etc. where data is split into various parts according to mentioned fold. CV, then perform training on each fold and expose accuracy based on different features passed to the CV. Now you have an idea about your data and you also know which feature works best with the crunch of your data. After this process, you start actual model training and prediction on live data (that's why you call fit again).

CV has a number of benefit which you can browse to get deep information.